# search string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Hello I've two dataframes. One is master db1 (it has many rows) the second is sourcetarget (it is smaller). I want to look at **db1** all words in **sourcetarget** then if it matches I will create a new boolean column (0,1). I tried out this code (which has high complexity) but I always get 0. What is wrong?

````
start_time = time.time()

compt=0
for i in db1.clean_nomComplet:
    for j in sourcetarget.sourcetarget:
        res0 = i.find(j)
        if res0 >= 0:     
            db1['top'] = 1
        else:
            db1['top'] = 0
    compt+=1    
    print(compt/len(db1)*100,end="\r")
    if compt%50000 == 0:
        print("../data_out/sauve"+str(compt)+'.csv')
        db1.to_csv('../data_out/sauve'+str(compt)+'.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))```
````

Comment: Please add headers of your `dataframes`

Comment: you need to do a join before doing that

Comment: It's private. In db1.clean_nomComplet I've name of companies that can be one or N string. In sourcetarget.sourcetarget I've one string keyword per line. At first time I've to cols in sourcetarget.sourcetarget but I concate theme to one.

Comment: @Nikaido where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found to do these kind of comparison is:

```
#1. You transform the values you want to check on as a set
# because you don't care about having them ordered. This saves A LOT of complexity
source = set(sourcetarget.sourcetarget.values)

# 2. Use the isin function
db1['top'] = 0
db1.loc[db1['clean_nomComplet'].isin(source), 'top'] = 1
```

---

The problem on your script is that you change the value of the whole column. You should rather use:

```
for index, row in db1.iterrows():
    [...]
    if res0 >= 0:     
        db1.loc[index,'top'] = 1
    else:
        db1[index, 'top'] = 0
```

Comment: thanks for commplexity explaination, so in [...] I'll put ```db1.loc[db1['clean_nomComplet'].isin(source), 'top'] = 1```?

Comment: Well you can just use the first part of my answer without iterating. Otherwise it would look something like `if row['clean_nomComplet'] in set_:`

Comment: Yes the first one worked. So I should better delete ```if res0 >= 0:  ```?

Comment: I tested the second option like this https://imgur.com/a/N4oMYIy

Comment: Seems good ! But be careful your `db1.to_csv()` seems to be in your for loop :)